# how to handle blob sent via javascript through websocket back at the python server?

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, opencv, websocket

i have to process the image back at the python server with Opencv . the blob goes to the python server but i could not figure out how to convert this blob back into image with openCV

```
 //this is my javascript function to send image converted to blob, 
//back to my python server
         function () {

             ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 320, 240);
            var data = canvas.get()[0].toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
             newblob = dataURItoBlob(data);
             ws.send(newblob);

            }
```

this is my python backend handling

```
class EchoServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

       def onMessage(self, msg, binary):
         img = # here the code to convert blob into the image
         blur = cv2.blur(img, (5, 5))
         hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
         msg = hsv
         print "the image:", msg
         #conver the image back to blob and reply back to the websocket
         #havent written the code for this part yet
         self.sendMessage(msg, binary)
```

please help me figure this out

Comment: Try looking at the network tab in your developer tools to see how a blob is sent through a websocket.

Comment: it's probably b64 encoded, after that use imdecode to make a cv image from the jpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out how this blob is getting made and then reverse engineer it